# How can I get the result from mysql after group and order

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables

`t1`

| id | stage |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2,3 |
| 2 | 2,3,4 |

`t2`

| id | t_id | stage_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 4 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 |

I hope the result can first order by `t2.t_id` and then order by the value of `t1.stage`

like the following result

| t_id | stage_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

I have the following sql ,but it do not work.So what should I do?

```
SELECT
    t2.t_id,
    t2.stage_id
FROM
    t2
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.t_id
GROUP BY
    t2.t_id,
    t2.stage_id
ORDER BY
    t2.t_id,
    field(t2.stage_id, t1.stage)
```

Comment: `FIELD()` requires each value to be a separate argument, not a single comma-separated string.

Comment: Use `FIND_IN_SET()` instead of `FIELD()`

Comment: Why do you use GROUP BY if you don't do any aggregation? Why not simply `ORDER BY t2.t_id, t2.stage_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FIELD()` requires each value to sort by to be a separate argument.

[`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) returns the index in a comma-separated string.

```
SELECT
    t2.t_id,
    t2.stage_id
FROM
    t2
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.t_id
GROUP BY
    t2.t_id,
    t2.stage_id
ORDER BY
    t2.t_id,
    find_in_set(t2.stage_id, t1.stage)
```

Note that this only corrects the ordering criteria in your SQL. This won't necessarily return the first row in each group by that ordering (and will get an error if the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode is enabled). See [SQL Selecting from two Tables with inner join and limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145885/sql-selecting-from-two-tables-with-inner-join-and-limit?noredirect=1&lq=1) for the correct way to do that.

Comment: You know this will produce an error because of `t1.stage` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=432e918fb5cd09d64e11a8dba69b03a3

Comment: @ErgestBasha Thanks. I've added a caveat about that.