# MySQL LEFT JOIN ON THE MAX of computed columns

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

`students`

```
|id_number| name
| 1001 | Brian | 
| 1002 | John |
```

`terms`

```
| id | year | term | label | 
| 10 | 2022 | 3 | Summer | 
| 11 | 2023 | 1 | 1st Sem | 
| 12 | 2023 | 2 | 2nd Sem | 
| 13 | 2023 | 3 | Summer |
```

`history`

```
|id_number | terms_id | section |
| 1002 | 11 | Oak |
| 1002 | 13 | Fig |
| 1002 | 12 | Daisy |
| 1001 | 10 | Daisy |
```

Now I want to get the most recent section of each student. All these three tables are expected to be populated with more rows in  the coming years.

Desired Result:

```
| id_number | section | 
| 1002 | Fig   |
| 1001 | Daisy |
```

I tried this query but I think I lack something or am having the wrong logic. Note that `year*3+term` will help me achieve the terms in the right order, i.e, 1st, 2nd and summer order.

```
SELECT s.id_number, h.section
FROM students s 
LEFT JOIN history h ON s.idno = h.idno 
LEFT JOIN terms t ON t.id = h.terms_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, year*3 + term AS ext_term FROM terms) ext ON ext.id = t.id 
WHERE 
    t.id = (
        SELECT MAX(ext_term) 
        FROM ext
        WHERE ext.id = t.id
   )
```

Comment: If you just want one row, write the query that joins all of John's rows, then add `ORDER BY terms_id DESC LIMIT 1`.

Comment: What is stopping you getting your desired result? Please include your current attempt and explain where it's not working.

Comment: @Stu I'ved updated my question.

Comment: @Barmar terms_id does not necessarily give the most recent. I update my question and I'm pretty sure `year*3+term` will give the right sequence and hence I can get the most recent one.

Comment: Is `idno` supposed to be `id_number`? Why make things confusing by changing the column names between the sample tables and query?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY year DESC, term DESC LIMIT 1` to get the most recent year and the latest term within that year.

```
SELECT s.idno, h.section
FROM students s 
LEFT JOIN history h ON s.idno = h.idno 
LEFT JOIN terms t ON t.id = h.terms_id
WHERE s.name = 'John'
ORDER BY t.year DESC, t.term DESC
LIMIT 1
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/PbxwaATYNkys2usds3DME/0)

Multiplying the year and adding the term is equivalent, but more confusing in my opinion.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I did not emphasize I would want to get all students with their respective most recent terms

Comment: You specifically said "of John", and your attempted code has `AND h.idno = 1002`. You denied that you wanted all student's results.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145885/sql-selecting-from-two-tables-with-inner-join-and-limit?noredirect=1&lq=1 for how to do it for all students.